# What is TestBed in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I am new to Jasmine with Angular 2, I am frequently working with the TestBed object when writting a Testcase and getting the error:`Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.`

How do I solve this error?

```
@Component({
  moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app-component.html',

})
```

Comment: Did you try calling `TestBed.compileComponents()`? `TestBed` is a mock environment to run Angular2 component tests without the browser.

Comment: Yes, but now it says  Error: Cannot create the component AppComponent as it was not imported into the testing module!

Comment: Did you check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test

This call is required when testing components using `templateUrl`

> Error: Cannot create the component AppComponent as it was not imported into the testing module!

You need to configure the `TestBed` before each test, adding any components, modules and services you need for the test. It's just like configuring an regular `@NgModule` from scratch, but you just add what you need.

```
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [],
    imports: []
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));

it('...', () => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
});
```

**See Also**

- [Angular testing docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing) for many more complete examples.

Comment: Why do we use TestBed?

Comment: To configure a module for the testing environment.